# Garry's Mod Server - Friend can't see addon contents in spawn list

Tags: mods, garrys-mod

So I made a Garry's Mod server for my friend and I, and I got addons and enabled FastDL. The addons worked, but my friend couldn't see the addons in the spawnlist. He looked under browse and addons, but only saw his addons that he has gotten himself. How do I fix this so he can see the addons also?

Comment: What addon is it? Can he see them when you spawn them? Is the issue just not being able to spawn it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your FastDL is not set up properly, here is how to do it.

### Setting up Workshop downloads for server

1. Create an auth key http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey

   Use your server's IP (Without the port)
2. Create a new text file in the same location as your `SRCDS.exe` in your server files and rename it to `start.bat` then open it up with your favorite notepad (notepad.exe is default with Windows)
3. Paste the following into `start.bat`

   ```
   @echo off
   cls
   echo Protecting srcds from crashes...
   echo If you want to close srcds, close the srcds window and type Y depending on your language followed by Enter.
   title Server Watchdog
   :srcds
   echo (%time%) srcds started.
   start /wait srcds.exe -console -game garrysmod +map gm_construct +maxplayers 16
   echo (%time%) WARNING: srcds closed or crashed, restarting.
   goto srcds
   ```
4. On line 9 you may change what the default map, maximum players, gamemode, etc. can be

   (to change gamemode type `+gamemode NAME` where NAME is the gamemode code name, you can Google what the gamemode code names are, sandbox is default)
5. On line 9 you want to add `-authkey YOUR AUTHKEY HERE`
6. Now you will want to create a collection of all the addons you want your server to have by going to the [Create collection page](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/editcollection/?appid=4000)
7. Follow the on-screen instructions
8. Once you have finished, Take the URL of the workshop collection (example: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=298302791)
9. Copy the digits after the `?id=` in the url (example: 298302791)
10. Now go back to the `start.bat` file and on line 9 type `+host_workshop_collection COLLECTION ID`
11. Replace `COLLECTION ID` with the digits after `?id=` from the URL

### Setting up Workshop downloads for client

1. Go to `C:\GMOD SERVER FOLDER\garrysmod\lua\autorun\server`
2. Create a file called `workshop.lua` (change the ending of a .txt file to .lua)
3. Open `workshop.lua` with your favorite notepad (notepad.exe is default with Windows)
4. Now locate your Workshop Addon on [the workshop website](http://steamcommunity.com/app/4000/workshop/)
5. Take the URL of the workshop item (example: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=370857063)
6. Copy the digits after the `?id=` in the url (example: 370857063)
7. Now go back to the `workshop.lua` file and type `resource.AddWorkshop("WORKSHOP ID")`
8. Replace `WORKSHOP ID` with the digits after `?id=` from the URL
9. Go to the next line
10. Repeat steps 4-9 for ***EVERY*** workshop item

Example:

```
resource.AddWorkshop("123456789")
resource.AddWorkshop("987654321")
resource.AddWorkshop("192837465")
```

***The quotation marks are important***

Comment: Make sure it's a string for the `resource.AddWorkshop()` function... since someone thought it'd be a good idea to make it do that.

Comment: @Codingale what do you mean?

Comment: Doing `resouce.AddWorkshop(123456789)` causes an error saying it takes a string, not a number... the IDs are numbers by default forcing you to add extra quotes around them for it to work see: http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/resource/AddWorkshop

Comment: @Codingale that is why I did `resource.AddWorkshop("123456789")` because you need the quotes

Comment: Just wanted to remind everyone since that isn't expected if you're savvy in coding, so it's easy to mistake it for taking a number or a string.

Comment: @Codingale ok, and I made an edit to make sure they use quotation marks